# delegate don't work between 2 viewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I get stuck on using the delegate method.

I have 2 views. In view A, I use a delegate to say I pressed a button to view B. 
View B receives the message well. 
I would like to sent a message to say that the view B has received the message.

So the view from A to B for my delegate works but the B to A is not working.

```
.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ButtonProtocolName <NSObject>
- (void)toucheEnter:(id)sender;      
@end

@interface ClavierKsViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ButtonProtocolName> delegate;
@end


.m
#import "ClavierKsViewController.h"

@interface ClavierKsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ClavierKsViewController

-(IBAction)toucheEntreeClavier:(id)sender{
     [self.delegate toucheEnter:sender];
}
@end
```

Now on view B.h:

```
#import "ClavierKsViewController.h"
@interface CaisseViewController : UIViewController<ButtonProtocolName>
@property (nonatomic,retain) ClavierKsViewController *clavierKsView;
```

b.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    clavierKsView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"clavierKsView"];

    clavierKsView.delegate=self;
}

-(void)toucheEnter:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"valider");
}
```

in that sense it works
When I created a delegate from view B to view A in based on the same way, I still get the same message: can not find protocol declaration for delegate

Comment: Do you try to send message to `ClavierKsViewController` from `CaisseViewController`? Hence `CaisseViewController` hold the instance of `ClavierKsViewController`, you can just send message to `ClavierKsViewController` instead of create another delegate.

Comment: how i can send the message?

Comment: like usual [`claverKsView someMessage]`

Comment: ok it's work like that tks! but i dont understand why my delegate not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol cannot work is likely caused by circular dependency. The solution is to extract your protocol to another .h like "ButtonProtocolName.h" and import the protocol in both a.h and b.h